# Is it normal to see my containerized app running when I type "ps ax" from the host OS?

Tags: docker

I have a working image that I'm able to launch containers from like so

```
docker run -d -p 53:53/tcp -p 53:53/udp  my_lil_bind9
```

When I run `ps ax |grep named` from the host OS I see

```
3197 ?  Ssl  0:00 /usr/sbin/named -g -c /etc/bind/named.conf -u bind
```

and I see the same thing (`/usr/sbin/named -g -c /etc/bind/named.conf -u bind`) from inside the running container. That seems wrong. Shouldn't I only see named running inside the container? PID of named inside the container is 1.

Am I launching the container incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.

Everything running inside the container is visible to the host. It's a container, not a VM.

What you will NOT see in the host (by default) are port bindings. Containers run in their own namespace, so to see their own port bindings instead of the bindings of Docker you need to look in those namespaces.

Comment: This seems so counterintuitive to me. Thanks.